# Removing Debug and Release Configurations from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, deployment, configuration, visual-studio-debugging

I modified the default Debug configuation, so that the output directories resemble `$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)/$(ConfigurationName)`.

Next, I created debug variations, `DebugStatic` and `DebugDll`, to be more explicit about the target being created.  I created them by copying the `Debug` configuration.

In similar fashion, I created `ReleaseDLL` and `ReleaseStatic` from the modified `Release` configuration.

Using *Configuration Manager*, I removed the `Debug` and `Release` configurations.

The `Debug` and `Release` configurations still show up in the *Batch Build window* and also in the *Configuration* drop down box in the *Property Pages* window (displayed from right clicking on the project name, then selecting *Properties*).

### How do I cleanse, wipe-out, erase, obliterate, the `Debug` and `Release` configurations?

*(The ambiguity of Debug has caused me many weeks of problem solving, especially when accidentally combining a Win32 debug DLL in an X64 project)*
*(I searched the web and StackOverflow, but didn't find anything about completely removing those configurations.)*

Comment: They are probably still in the .sln file.  You can delete them with a text editor.  They are bound to come back when you add a new project btw, you are fighting the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution and Project debug/release configurations are different.

Solution configurations may be controlled by configuration manager (Active Solution Configuration) and project configuration again can be controlled in the same manager for each project separately(project context)

[image]

In the image above, you can click on a project configuration, select edit and then you can remove the configuration.

Comment: So how do I get the `Debug` and `Release` configurations out of the project configurations?

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I wanted to respond to @ThomasMatthews.  When you click 'edit' on the project's configuration in the table shown above, you can remove the configuration from the -project-.  To fully remove it from the solution you will need to drop down the box at the top left ('Active Solution Configuration') and choose 'edit'.  This will allow you to remove the configurations from the -solution-.

Comment: Is it possible to remove a certain configuration from 20-100 projects (at the same time / using a single step)?

Comment: @cppBeginner, yes, it is possible,  to fully remove a configuration for all projects from the solution you will need to select drop down at the top left ('Active Solution Configuration') and choose 'edit'. This will allow you to remove or rename any configuration you want

Comment: The step you just mentioned can remove a configuration from solution, but not from any projects.   If I do it, then click the project combo box (as in the image in your answer), the configuration will still exist in the pop-up list (similar as shown in the image) of every projects.

Comment: @cppBeginner I agree it is ridiculous to delete a hundred project configurations one click at a time. fortunately there is a way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968790/7098259

Answer (score 1):

Note that to clear this from VS Batch build you must manually delete the property groups for DEBUG & RELEASE configurations from the project file XML.

```html
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the configurations within the .SLN file

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    **Undesired Debug**|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {CE94D753-36C5-45FA-870A-4D61DAC98B71}.**Undesired Debug** .Net Native (Debug)|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {4EFA1043-8E1B-4950-8167-C77ABE626F1E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {4EFA1043-8E1B-4950-8167-C77ABE626F1E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {4EFA1043-8E1B-4950-8167-C77ABE626F1E}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {4EFA1043-8E1B-4950-8167-C77ABE626F1E}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {28D34A34-6E07-4FC3-A4B3-C704C1C5C7CE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {28D34A34-6E07-4FC3-A4B3-C704C1C5C7CE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {28D34A34-6E07-4FC3-A4B3-C704C1C5C7CE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {28D34A34-6E07-4FC3-A4B3-C704C1C5C7CE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {6B71D000-AC8D-49AF-ADA6-D96C7ECFF093}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {6B71D000-AC8D-49AF-ADA6-D96C7ECFF093}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {6B71D000-AC8D-49AF-ADA6-D96C7ECFF093}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {6B71D000-AC8D-49AF-ADA6-D96C7ECFF093}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {CE94D753-36C5-45FA-870A-4D61DAC98B71}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {CE94D753-36C5-45FA-870A-4D61DAC98B71}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {CE94D753-36C5-45FA-870A-4D61DAC98B71}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {CE94D753-36C5-45FA-870A-4D61DAC98B71}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```