# How do you remove project configurations in Batch Build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How do you remove project configurations in Batch Build?

I created a new configuration `Test`, and used the Visual Studio Batch Build option to build the various configuration / solution config pairs

I didn't need the configuration and deleted it

But the `Test` / `Debug|Any CPU` and `Test` / `Release|Any` CPU pairs are still present in the Batch Build dialog, and there isn't a delete option

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003043/removing-debug-and-release-configurations-from-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 1):

While solution configurations can be removed using the `EDIT` option in the drop down within the configuration manager dialog, if you switch to batch build you still see Debug & Release configurations! 
[Click here to see how I got rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031239/2614926)